# Arrow function VS normal function in Array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I was solving some JS challenges and noticed that when using arrow function the result comes as expected, when i try same code using normal function it doesn't. 
Can someone explain the difference or i might have a typo!!

here is the first solution (works):

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.split(' ').map(i =>  i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ')
    return str;
  }
   console.log(titleCase("I'm a liTTle tea pot")); // I'm A Little Tea Pot
```

And the second solution with normal function (returns empty string):

```
function titleCase2(str) {
    str = str.split(' ').map(function(i, index){ i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substr(1).toLowerCase()}).join(' ')
    return str;
  }
   console.log(titleCase2("I'm a liTTle tea pot")); // empty string
```

[image: Screenshot of my console]

[You can use My Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9KRLW5oMdFUbRsftnmIF?p=preview)

Comment: if I remember the spec correctly, one line arrow functions return whatever that line is. Regular functions don't do that by default

Comment: 1-line arrow functions implicitly `return` the line - regular functions need explicit `return`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You miss a `return` keyword inside the callback function.

Fat-arrow function returns a value by default, the `return` keyword is built-in. To get the value from the normal function expression, you have to return it.

```js
function titleCase2(str) {
  str = str.split(' ').map(function(i, index) {
    return i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  }).join(' ')
  return str;
}
console.log(titleCase2("I'm a liTTle tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need explicit `return` for non-arrow functions. 1-line arrow functions implicitly return the result of that one line.

```
function titleCase2(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function(i, index){ return i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substr(1).toLowerCase()}).join(' ')
}
console.log(titleCase2("I'm a liTTle tea pot")); // I'm A Little Tea Pot
```